# Y-axis labels disappear when add values using C3

Tags: r, c3.js

The C3 chart prints OK if I don't try to explicitly state the values for the y-axis. However, I find the labels messy.

If I try to force y-axis label values, no labels are printed.

Yet, the third example shows that they can work.

Why do they not work in example #2?

R Script

```
library("c3")
library("tidyverse")

df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18503, 18504, 18505, 18506, 
                                        18507, 18508, 18509, 18510, 18511, 18512, 18513, 18514, 18515, 
                                        18516, 18517, 18518, 18519), class = "Date"), A = c(1.6, 1.6, 
                                                                                            1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 
                                                                                            1.6, 1.6), B = c(1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 
                                                                                                             1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8), C = c(1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 
                                                                                                                                                            1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 
                                                                                                                                                            1.75, 1.75, 1.75), D = c(1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75
                                                                                                                                                            ), E = c(1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 
                                                                                                                                                                     1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "tbl", "data.frame"))
# Example 1 ###############################
# Y-axis labels are there, but messy
df %>% 
  c3()

# Example 2 ###############################
# No Y-axis labels
df %>% 
  c3() %>% 
  tickAxis('y', values = c(0, 1, 2))

# Example 3 ###############################
# Clean Y-axis labels
data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,2), b = c(2,4,1,5)) %>%
  c3() %>%
  tickAxis('y', values = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works. Your `min` y axis value is `1.58` and `max` is `1.8`. Since you have given `c(0,1,2)`, it is not showing in the plot as it is magnified.

Try the below values and you will see the axis values.

```
df %>% 
  c3() %>% 
  tickAxis('y', values = c(1.6,1.65,1.7,1.8,1.81))
```

**Output:**

[image]